# Spark use reduceByKey on nested structure

Tags: scala, nested, apache-spark, rdd

Currently I have a structure like this:
`Array[(Int, Array[(String, Int)])]`, and I want to use `reduceByKey` on the `Array[(String, Int)]`, which is inside the Array of tuple. I tried code like

```
//data is in Array[(Int, Array[(String, Int)])] structure
val result = data.map(l => (l._1, l._2.reduceByKey(_ + _)))
```

The error is telling that `Array[(String,Int)]`does not have method called reduceByKey, and I understand that this method can only be used on RDD. So my question is, is there any way to use "reduceByKey" feature, doesn't need to use exactly this method, in the nested structure?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

You simply use `Array`'s `reduce` method here as you are now working with an `Array` and not an `RDD` (assuming you really meant the outer wrapper to be an `RDD`)

```
val data = sc.parallelize(List((1,List(("foo", 1), ("foo", 1)))))
data.map(l=>(l._1, l._2.foldLeft(List[(String, Int)]())((accum, curr)=>{
  val accumAsMap = accum.toMap
  accumAsMap.get(curr._1) match {
    case Some(value : Int) => (accumAsMap + (curr._1 -> (value + curr._2))).toList
    case None => curr :: accum 
  }
}))).collect
```

Ultimately, it seems that you do not understand what an `RDD` is, so you might want to read some of the docs on them.

Comment: Sorry man, your solution doesn't work. The error says "require String, but found (String, Int)". I just can not find the API on the internet. I want something works like `reduceByKey`.

Comment: You are working with a scala API, that is why you can't find it...NOT an RDD. And, sorry you want a reduceLeft (which allows type changing). Updated my answer

Comment: Still doesn't work. I am trying to reduce by key, which means that for each `(String, Int)` tuples in the array, combine all the tuples that have same String by adding those ints together. I don't think there is a way to do this with `reduce` or `reduceLeft`. I tried custom reduce function, but the input and output type doesn't fit for the argument.

Comment: I wasn't paying attention to the types. I updated my answer so that it works (I verified this time)